# Check first character in a string - telephone number

Tags: .net, vb.net, string

Could you please help me with the validation of a phone number? I have already validated it to have 11 characters, but I don't know how to make a condition for the first character to be 0.

Thank you!

Here is the code:

```
Do
        tel_no(n) = InputBox("Enter the telephone number")
        If Len(tel_no(n)) < 11 Or Len(tel_no(n)) > 11 Then
            MsgBox("The telephone number should have 11  digits and should start with 0")
        End If

Loop Until Len(tel_no(n)) = 11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to validate it this way :

```
.......
tel_no(n) = InputBox("Enter the telephone number")
If (tel_no(n).Length <> 11) Or (tel_no(n)(0) <> "0") Then
    MsgBox("The telephone number should have 11  digits and should start with 0")
End If
.......
```

That will make sure that `tel_no(n)` has length exactly 11, and has character in index 0 (the first character) equals zero (`0`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim conditionMet As Boolean = False

Do
    Dim phoneNumber As String = InputBox("Enter the telephone number")

    conditionMet = phoneNumber.Length = 11 And phoneNumber.StartsWith("0")

    If Not conditionMet Then
        MsgBox("The telephone number should have 11 digits and should start with 0")
    Else
        tel_no(n) = phoneNumber
    End If

Loop Until conditionMet
```

I should mention though that your user would have a much better UI experience if you showed him a [`MaskedTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: I have used the one above, 'cause it was shorter. This seems good as well anyway. Cheers for help.